# Regex to retrieve two variables between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, object

Im trying to retrieve two variables between two double brackets. So far I have this:

```
var regex = /\[\[\s([a-z]+):*\s*([\d])*\s\]\]/g;
var obj = {};
var text = '[[ dogs: 1 ]] [[ dogs: 2 ]] [[ cats: 1 ]]';
var module = text.replace(regex, function (match, key, value) {
    obj[key] = value;
    console.log(obj);
});
```

The outcome is:

```
Object {dogs: "2", cats: "1"}
```

What I want is:

```
Object {dogs: "1", dogs: "2", cats: "1"}
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why dogs only shows the 2nd id.

Comment: Why are you assigning two different values to one attribute...?

Comment: You are overwriting the key. Try using an array instead of an object.

Comment: Try entering `({dogs: "1", dogs: "2", cats: "1"})` into your JavaScript console.

Comment: In addition to overwriting the _key_'s value, you do have a problem with the regex. So far, nobody has spotted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because objects cannot contain multiple items with the same key. When you set `dogs` the second time, it overwrites the first instance.

Some alternate solutions include creating an array of objects:

```
var regex = /\[\[\s([a-z]+):*\s*([\d])*\s\]\]/g;
var arr = [];
var text = '[[ dogs: 1 ]] [[ dogs: 2 ]] [[ cats: 1 ]]';
var module = text.replace(regex, function (match, key, value) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    arr.push(obj);
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Or using creating an object of arrays:

```
var regex = /\[\[\s([a-z]+):*\s*([\d])*\s\]\]/g;
var obj = {};
var text = '[[ dogs: 1 ]] [[ dogs: 2 ]] [[ cats: 1 ]]';
var module = text.replace(regex, function (match, key, value) {
    if (obj[key]) {
        obj[key].push(value);
    } else {
        obj[key] = [value];
    }
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your bug is not inside the regex is inside the object.

You can't have an object with two identical keys.

I suggest you put your data into array and iterate when you need it :

```
var regex = /\[\[\s([a-z]+):*\s*([\d])*\s\]\]/g;
var arr = [];
var text = '[[ dogs: 1 ]] [[ dogs: 2 ]] [[ cats: 1 ]]';
var module = text.replace(regex, function (match, key, value) {
    var obj = {}
    obj[key] = value;
    arr.push(obj);
});
console.log(arr); // [{dogs:1},{dogs:2},{cats:1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you cant have multiple properties with the same name my suggestion is that you use an array to store different values, like this;

http://jsbin.com/qiqacifata/1/edit?js,console

```
var regex = /\[\[\s([a-z]+):*\s*([\d])*\s\]\]/g;
var obj = {};
var text = '[[ dogs: 1 ]] [[ dogs: 2 ]] [[ cats: 1 ]]';
var module = text.replace(regex, function (match, key, value) {
    if(!obj[key]) {
        obj[key] = [];
    }
    obj[key].push(value);

});

console.log(obj);
```

Results in;

```
{
  cats: ["1"],
  dogs: ["1", "2"]
}
```